# How to get Request.User in Django-Rest-Framework serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've tried something like this, it does not work.

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post

    def save(self):
        user = self.context['request.user']
        title = self.validated_data['title']
        article = self.validated_data['article']
```

I need a way of being able to access request.user from my Serializer class.

Comment: DRF `CurrentUserDefault` is absolutely ❤️ http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault

Answer (score 380, accepted):

You cannot access the `request.user` directly. You need to access the request object, and then fetch the user attribute.

Like this:

```
user =  self.context['request'].user
```

Or to be more safe,

```
user = None
request = self.context.get("request")
if request and hasattr(request, "user"):
    user = request.user
```

More on [extra context can be read here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context)

Comment: it says `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

Comment: of course, this was in the context of a class. You are most likely not in the context of a class

Comment: In my serializer, in `validate()` method, self.context is an empty dict. Why?

Comment: David - you probably solved this long ago, but if anyone else has this issue, it could be because you are constructing your serializer manually.  I had this problem in a nested serializer instantiated for a generic relationship.  The docs say to do serializer = NoteSerializer(value) but this will only pass your instance, not the context containing the request.  You can pass kwargs to the constructor and send it the info it needs (see get_serializer or GenericAPIView for how it does it)

Comment: @JonVaughan any detail how to pass kwargs to the serializer instance??

Comment: Adding to @JonVaughan comment you can call the method get_serializer_context just like GenericAPIView does:

`serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
kwargs['context'] = self.get_serializer_context()
 return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 88):

Actually, you don't have to bother with context. There is a much better way to do it:

```
from rest_framework.fields import CurrentUserDefault

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post

   def save(self):
        user = CurrentUserDefault()  # <= magic!
        title = self.validated_data['title']
        article = self.validated_data['article']
```

Comment: It did not work,its returning a Null object.
user_edit = serializers.CurrentUserDefault()

Comment: @EndersonMenezes It's probably best worked with the `IsAuthenticated` permission.

Comment: Not fully related, but interesting: I have readwrite PrimaryKeyRelatedField and I need to filter possibilities (which are users addresses) for current user only. I made derrived class  MyAddresses(PrimaryKeyRelatedField) and I try rewrite get_queryset() there using .filter(user=..). I have problem to get request.user there. Additionally I have no success with user=CurrentUserDefault(). However I have success and can access the user by calling it: CurrentUserDefault()(self) makes the trick. [self relates to the MyAddresses class/object]

Answer (score 60):

As Igor mentioned in other answer, you can use CurrentUserDefault. If you do not want to override save method just for this, then use [doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault):

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    class Meta:
        model = Post
```

Comment: doc link is now mislinked.

Comment: Link to the official DRF documentation with this same example
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-read-only-fields

Comment: I used `HiddenField` instead of `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` without read `read_only` attiribute, it works. As I understood there is no security problem.

Answer (score 18):

Use this code in view:

```
serializer = UploadFilesSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
```

then access it with this in serializer:

```
user = self.context.get("request").user
```

Answer (score 12):

CurrentUserDefault
A default class that can be used to represent the current user. In order to use this, the 'request' must have been provided as part of the context dictionary when instantiating the serializer.

in views.py

```py
serializer = UploadFilesSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
```

## This is example to pass request

in serializers.py

```py
owner = serializers.HiddenField(
    default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
)
```

[Source From Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault)

Answer (score 10):

For those who used Django's ORM and added the user as a foreign key, they will need to include the user's entire object, and I was only able to do this in the create method and removing the mandatory field:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

def create(self, validated_data):
    
    request = self.context.get("request")
    
    post = Post()
    post.title = validated_data['title']
    post.article = validated_data['article']
    post.user = request.user

    post.save()

    return post

class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = '__all__'
    extra_kwargs = {'user': {'required': False}}
```

Comment: `request = self.context.get("request")` is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 7):

You can pass `request.user` when calling `.save(...)` inside a view:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Event
        exclude = ['user']


class EventView(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        es = EventSerializer(data=request.data)
        if es.is_valid():
            es.save(user=self.request.user)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(data=es.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This is the model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    place = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Comment: The `exclude = ['user']` did the job for me. I had declared it as `write_only = True` but with your solution is not needed anymore. Much more clear than defining it as `read_only = True`

Answer (score 6):

### In GET method:

Add `context={'user': request.user}` in the View class:

```py
class ContentView(generics.ListAPIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content_list = <Respective-Model>.objects.all()
        serializer = ContentSerializer(content_list, many=True, 
                                       context={'user': request.user})
```

Get it in the Serializer class method:

```py
class ContentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rate = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_rate(self, instance):
        user = self.context.get("user") 
        ...  
    ...
```

### In POST method:

Follow other answers (e.g. [Max's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58774665/3702377)).

Answer (score 4):

You need a small edit in your serializer:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post

    def save(self):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        title = self.validated_data['title']
        article = self.validated_data['article']
```

Here is an example, using Model mixing viewsets. In `create` method you can find the proper way of calling the serializer. [get_serializer](http://www.cdrf.co/3.9/rest_framework.viewsets/GenericViewSet.html#get_serializer_context) method fills the context dictionary properly. If you need to use a different serializer then defined on the viewset, see the `update` method on how to initiate the serializer with context dictionary, which also passes the request object to serializer.

```
class SignupViewSet(mixins.UpdateModelMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    http_method_names = ["put", "post"]
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
        instance = self.get_object()
        kwargs['context'] = self.get_serializer_context()
        serializer = PostSerializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial, **kwargs)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)    
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can not access `self.context.user` directly. First you have to pass the `context` inside you serializer. For this follow steps bellow:

1. Some where inside your api view:

   ```
    class ApiView(views.APIView):
        def get(self, request):
            items = Item.object.all()
            return Response(
                ItemSerializer(
                     items, 
                     many=True,
                     context=request  # <- this line (pass the request as context)
                ).data
            )
   ```
2. Then inside your serializer:

   ```
    class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        current_user = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_user')

        class Meta:
            model = Item
            fields = (
                'id',
                'name',
                'current_user',
            )

        def get_user(self, obj):
            request = self.context
            return request.user  # <- here is current your user
   ```

Answer (score 3):

The solution can be simple for this however I tried accessing using `self.contenxt['request'].user` but not working in the serializer.

If you're using DRF obviously login via token is the only source or maybe others that's debatable.

Moving toward a solution.

Pass the `request.user` instance while creating `serializer.create`

views.py

```
if serializer.is_valid():
            watch = serializer.create(serializer.data, request.user)
```

serializer.py

```
 def create(self, validated_data, usr):
    return Watch.objects.create(user=usr, movie=movie_obj, action=validated_data['action'])
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to get current user inside serializer is like this.

```
AnySerializer(data={
        'example_id': id
    }, context={'request': request})
```

This has to be written in views.py
And now in Serializer.py part

```
user = serializers.CharField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
```

This "user" must be your field in Model as any relation like foreign key

Answer (score 1):

If you are using generic views and you want to inject current user at the point of saving the instance then you can override [`perform_create`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_serializer_classself) or `perform_update`:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

`user` will be added as an attribute to `kwargs` and you can access it through `validated_data` in serializer

```
user = validated_data['user']
```

Answer (score 0):

[drf srz page](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)

in my project it worked my user field was read only so i needed to get
user id in the create method

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comment_replis = RecursiveField(many=True, read_only=True)
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = PostComment
        fields = ('_all_')

    def create(self, validated_data):
 


        post = PostComment.objects.create(**validated_data)   
        print(self._dict_['_kwargs']['data']["user"]) # geting #request.data["user"] #  <- mian code
        post.user=User.objects.get(id=self._dict_['_kwargs']['data']["user"])
        return post
```

in my project i tried this way and it work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You need to call `post.save()` after you called `post.user=...`, else the relation wont be stored in the database.

Answer (score 0):

as others answered, should use `self.context['request'].user` , but consider it does not work with **GenericAPIView** , should use **ListAPIView** or **RetrieveAPIView**

while **GenericAPIView** does not send **request** context to serializer