# DRF, add custom field to ModelSerializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have some models in my project and I need a especial response of the API, i'm using Django Rest framework.

```
class Goal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    # more fields

class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    goal = models.ForeignKey(Goal)

class UserTask(models.Model):
    goal = models.ForeignKey(Goal)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    # other fields
```

I have this response:

```
{
  "name": "One goal",
  "task": [
    {
      "name": "first task"
    },
    {
      "name": "second tas"
    }
  ]
}
```

But I need this:

```
{
  "name": "One goal",
  "task": [
    {
      "name": "first task",
      "is_in_usertask": true
    },
    {
      "name": "second tas",
      "is_in_usertask": false
    }
  ]
}
```

I saw [this in DRF docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-fields-explicitly) but I don't know how to filter `UserTask` by the current user (or other that is given in URL paramenter) and each `Goal`.

Edit:

```
# serializers

class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task


class GoalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # related_name works fine
    tasks = TaskSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Goal
```

Comment: Can you add your serializers ?

Comment: Also, whats the logic behind `is_in_usertask` became `True/False` ?

Comment: When the current user and the `Task` is in `UserTask`is `True`

Comment: I don't understand :(

Comment: If the current logged user and the `Task` are in `UserTask` then `is_in_usertask` should be `true`, in otherwise should be `false`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to use [`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) field as

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_in_usertask = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('name', 'is_in_usertask')

    def get_is_in_usertask(self, task):
        return UserTask.objects.filter(user=self.context['request'].user, goal=task.goal).exists()
```

Comment: I tried this, but I don't knew how to access to the user instance. I will try this. To access to url parameters is the same way?

Comment: Serializer's ,`context` contains few data by default, that are `request` and `view`. Django has the feature to get the logged-in user via `request.user` attribute

Comment: URL params are the attributes od request object. Which means that are accessible from your serializer as long as the context has request instance

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this conversation: [How to get Request.User in Django-Rest-Framework serializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203652/how-to-get-request-user-in-django-rest-framework-serializer)

You can't access to request.user directly

Answer (score 0):

**You can use VirtualFieldSerializer which is similar to SerializerMethodField**

```
from rest_framework.fields import Field

class VirtualFieldSerializer(Field):
    """Virtual serializer field for including the serialized representation of another serializer's data.
    This field is read-only, and gives flexibility in constructing complex serializer structures. """

    def __init__(self, serializer, **kwargs):
        self.serializer = serializer
        kwargs['source'] = '*'
        kwargs['read_only'] = True
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return self.serializer().to_representation(value)
```

**Example**

if You have **Contact** model, and **SmsChannel** model which have **OneToOne** relation to Contact you can get nested result like `{'channels': {'sms': {'status': 1, 'number': '1234'}}`

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    channels = VirtualFieldSerializer(ContactChannelsSerializer)

class ContactSmsChannelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SmsChannel
        fields = ('number', 'status')

class ContactChannelsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    sms = ContactSmsChannelSerializer(source='sms_channel')
```