# (1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null") with Django DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I wrote code to create new users via POST and DRF (Django Rest Framework) successfully and I can obtain token correctly, however when I try to POST (via DRF) to fill Profile linked to that user I get
(1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")

```
This is snippets of my code:
for serializers:
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email','first_name','last_name','password')
    def create(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = super().create(*args, **kwargs)
        p = user.password
        user.set_password(p)
        user.save()
        return user

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = super().update(*args, **kwargs)
        p = user.password
        user.set_password(p)

        user.save()
        return user

class ProfileSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
       
        fields = ('bio','birth_date','location','country')

    def create(self, *args, **kwargs):
        profile = super().create(*args, **kwargs)
        profile.save()
        return profile
    
    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        profile = super().update(*args, **kwargs)
        profile.save()
        return profile

and for views:
class ProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    permission_classes = IsAuthenticated,
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()


class UserViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet,mixins.CreateModelMixin,):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    #permission_classes= (IsAdminUser,)
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')

and for models:
@receiver(post_save, sender = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender,instance=None,created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)


class Country(models.Model):
    iso = models.CharField(max_length = 2,unique = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    iso3 = models.CharField(max_length = 6)
    phonecode = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.name
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.name

class Profile(models.Model):
    #user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default = "")
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default = "")
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.user
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.user

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()
```

When I try with Postman and I pass a token for token authentication, it recognize the token correctly but I get this error:
(1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null") with Django DRF
I appreciate your help to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Create() save to the database, so you need to set profile.user_id before calling the function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't understand what do you mean be save to the database, there is already profile.save() in the code, also from where I will get user_id value? Can you please give an example?

Comment: Create() calls this .save() inside it so your profile.save() is redundant , This is your code, you set user field to a foreign key with null nor allowed so you tell me where you shall get the information may be from request.user

Comment: This shall answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203652/how-to-get-request-user-in-django-rest-framework-serializer

Comment: for nested serializers you have to write your own create() and update() methods. Let me know if there is still an issue.